# How to transcode FLAC to mp3 on the fly

Tags: mp3, flac, minidlna, transcode

I am using `minidlna` / ReadyMedia-Server to stream my music files in my network.

Unfortunately one of my players is unable to read FLAC files, so I am looking into a solution on **how to transcode all FLAC files to mp3-format**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution, that should also work with other streaming services and is not bounded to `minidlna` / ReadyMedia

Check out **mp3fs** https://github.com/khenriks/mp3fs

Quote: *mp3fs is a read-only FUSE filesystem which transcodes between audio formats (currently FLAC and Ogg Vorbis to MP3) on the fly when opened and read.*

*This can let you use a FLAC or Ogg Vorbis collection with software and/or hardware which only understands the MP3 format, or transcode files through simple drag-and-drop in a file browser.*

---

I installed it via `sudo apt-get install mp3fs`

Mounted my Music-HDD folder that contains my FLAC and WAV files to the mp3fs filesystem:

```
sudo mp3fs -b 320 /home/alex/Music-HDD /home/alex/mp3-Music-HDD/ -o allow_other,ro
```

modified my `/etc/minidlna.conf` to point to the correct path:

```
media_dir=A,/home/alex/mp3-Music-HDD
```

and restarted the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart minidlna.service
```

Now my player is able to play the FLAC files.